# JSP insert SQL command

Tags: mysql, jsp

Ok, I have problem with MySQL insert command. I have 4 variables firstname, lastname, email, password and I want to insert them into my users table.

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into users(UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserEmail, UserPassword) values ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + pwd + ")");
```

When I use the above statement gives me this error;

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use**

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into users(UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserEmail, UserPassword) values (" + fisrtname + "," + lastname + "," + email + "," + password + ")");
```

When I use the above statement gives me this error;

**Unknown column 'bbb' in 'field list'**

PS: 'bbb' is string for fname, I type that for just try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed one single quote after pwd:

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into users(UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserEmail, UserPassword) values ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + pwd + "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:
On initial question the `'" + user + "'` existed, subsequently corrected by the author. See the comments below of the answer.**

Note that the INSERT stmt has four columns and five values:

```
st.executeUpdate("
    insert into users(
        UserFirstName, 
        UserLastName, 
        UserEmail, 
        UserPassword
    ) values (
        '" + fname + "',
        '" + lname + "',
        '" + email + "',
        '" + user + "',
        '" + pwd + "')
    ");
```

EDIT:
Remove the `user` value from VALUES. And insert more one `'` on `pwd` value.

Comment: I mistakenly post it there in my code they are even